# Combined Coefficient of Variation

Tags: coefficient-of-variation

I am doing a research in 12 participants where I perform two different techniques three times each, at different moments. I would like to calculate the combined CV (Mean CV1 + CV2 + CV3), but I don't know if this is statistically possible, and the best way to do it.

Comment: The usual method is to square the SDs to get variances, average the variances, take the sqrt of the avg of variances. For SDs 1, 3, 5 it's the difference between 3 and 3.4.// Variances of indep RVs are additive. SDs are not.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't explain myself. I would like to calculate the combined coefficient of variation.

Comment: Don't you need to find the SD in order to get the CV?

Comment: Yes I do. Can you please clarify your method?